# React Router failed prop 'history', is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've been following along Tyler Mcginnis' tutorial and hit a snag with the react router, specifically with history. I ended up copying his code verbatim just to see if it was only me, but I'm still getting

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-
in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's 
defined in.

Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `history` is marked as required in 
`Router`, but its value is `undefined`. in Router

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined
at new Router (index_bundle.js:8347)
at index_bundle.js:19079
at measureLifeCyclePerf (index_bundle.js:18859)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner (index_bundle.js:19078)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponent (index_bundle.js:19064)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (index_bundle.js:18972)
at Object.mountComponent (index_bundle.js:4070)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (index_bundle.js:19155)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (index_bundle.js:19042)
at Object.mountComponent (index_bundle.js:4070)
```

The implementation is:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var hashHistory = ReactRouter.hashHistory;
var IndexRoute = ReactRouter.IndexRoute;
var Main = require('../components/Main');
var Home = require("../components/Home");
var PromptContainer = require('../containers/PromptContainer');

var routes = (
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={Main}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home} />
      <Route path='playerOne' header='Player One' component={PromptContainer} />
      <Route path='playerTwo/:playerOne' header='Player Two' component={PromptContainer} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
);

module.exports = routes;
```

What I noticed was that `hashHistory` doesn't exist in the `react-router` module, but rather there is a `createBrowserHistory` inside the `history` module. Following the API doc I found, I figured I must call it through there as:

```
var BrowserHistory = require('history/createBrowserHistory);
const history = createBrowserHistory();
```

Doing that produces an `createBrowserHistory is not a function` error. Removing paranthesis, results in the same errors above stating history is `undefined`.

When I log history, it's definitely undefined, which makes me believe the issue has to do with the import statement, but wouldn't the console tell me `ReactRouter.hashHistory` could not be found?

I understand this tutorial is a year old and there have probably been changes to the API I just not aware of, and that's where my issue lies. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Router v4 is a little bit different

`HashHistory`

```
import { HashRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'; 
import App from './components/App'; 

render(( 
  <Router> 
    <Route exact path="/" component={App} /> 
  </Router> ), 
document.getElementById('root'));
```

or `BrowserHistory`

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'; 
import App from './components/App'; 

render(( 
  <Router> 
    <Route exact path="/" component={App} /> 
  </Router> ), 
document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I'm reverting to v3 to complete this tutorial, then I'll move onto v4 api, but it's good to know that those changes were made. I'll mark this as the answer, for others to see, thanks!

Comment: Multiple routes give error: "Uncaught Error: A <Router> may have only one child element". How to fix that?

Comment: @olefrank, what version of router? 

[This might help you](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4131), search where there is an answer with `Switch` tag in router.

Answer (score 0):

```
var BrowserHistory = require('history/createBrowserHistory');
const history = createBrowserHistory();
```

do you mean `var createBrowserHistory = require...`?

also, it looks like `createBrowserHistory` is now (in `v3`) located at `history/lib/createBrowserHistory`

If that doesn't work - what version of `react-router` are you using?

Comment: Right, createbrowserhistory.... I didn't copy paste that part. I'm using history version 4.6.1, and it's not in /lib either. Reactrouter is v 4.0.0

Comment: @JoeDahle yeah ok v4 broke a *lot* of things. If you're following a guide from a year ago, I'd use v3.

Comment: It is v4 that breaks everything, I reverted to v3.0.2, and everything works as hoped for, thanks!