# React-Router not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am so sorry to make the similar question with
[React Router v4 routes not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43456656/react-router-v4-routes-not-working)

because i not have enough reputation to comment the answer, so i create new question

i am so sorry about that

actually i have same problem, and i already try the solution from the answer
and follow https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start
but when i try to add 'exact' on route, its not show anything

i use

```
"react": "^16.0.0",
"react-router": "^4.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
```

and this is my app.js code

```
'use strict'

import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './home/home.js'
import Login from './login/'
import SignUp from './login/SignUp/'

render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Route path="/" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
),document.getElementById('container'));
```

**edit

this is my folder structure

[image]

** edit

finally i found the solution, 
this is my app.js code
    'use strict'

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
  HashRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './home/home.js'
import Login from './login/'
import SignUp from './login/SignUp/'

ReactDOM.render((
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
      <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
),document.getElementById('container'));
```

thanks

Comment: Where do you saved Login and Home components? May i know the path.? Because while importing you have mentioned an incomplete path './login/SignUp/'

Comment: i am sorry about that, i think the problem its not from component path because i have try to change <Route path="/" component={.....} /> with other component and its work correctly. my problem is when i try to use more than 1 route i can't access other route beside route root path

Comment: I am deleting my post, since I made an error. Sorry about it. `BrowserRouter` will render ALL the `Route`s which matches the given pattern. If we use `<Switch>`, only the first `<Route>` which matches will be rendered. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch

Comment: i already try to change <div> to <Switch>, i want to confirm something for <Route path="/" component={Login} />  if i go to http:localhost/my-project/ it will show the Login component right? when the url http:localhost/my-project/home it will show Home component(in my route code), but its not found i think the problem maybe in url

Comment: finally i found the solution, i change browserRouter to HashRouter. thank you all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Router failed prop 'history', is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42845303/react-router-failed-prop-history-is-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

You have to import `BrowserRouter as Router`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './home/home.js'
import Login from './login/'
import SignUp from './login/SignUp/'

ReactDOM.render((
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
      <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
),document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: i had try this before and still not work correctly, but thank you @nicholas

Comment: "You have to import BrowserHistory as Router"

Is this a typo?